# shell syntax in makefile

Tags: makefile

```
ifeq ($(KBUILD_SRC),)
```

I saw the above in `Makefile` of linux kernel.

It doesn't look like regular `if` statement in most other scripting languages AFAIK.

There's even no `endif` closing tag which exists in other places.

How does it work?

Comment: http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_7.html - What specifically don't you understand? (And there is an `endif` somewhere after it. Possibly not exactly where you expect it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifeq` checks if both statements are equal. As the second statement is empty, the statement basicalliy checks wether `$KBUILD_SRC` is empty/unset. By replacing `ifeq` with `ifneq` it sould check whether the variable is set.

The `endif` must be somewhere, otherwise there is a syntax error and `make` will complain.

And... as [Mario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9247844/246263) already explained, make uses two phases, the first one parses the Makefile and expands all macros, includes, etc. It also evaluates the conditionals. So afterwards all targets are created according the conditionals and other included Makefiles. In the second phase, make uses the targets and their dependencies (on other targets) to actually execute the commands (to build the kernel for example). The first target encountered is used as 'parent target', unless the make command included one or more 'parent targets'

Comment: Do you know what  `$(if $(KBUILD_EXTMOD),:$(KBUILD_EXTMOD))` means?

Comment: When `$(KBUILD_EXTMOD)` is set (ie it contains something) the command will return `:$(KBUILD_EXTMOD)`, otherwise nothing. It can be used to fill another variable or provide an argument of a command (a sort of inline if-statement). Again, it is processed 'phase 1' I described, before executing the actual targets/commands.

Comment: What does `:` in  `:$(KBUILD_EXTMOD)` mean?

Comment: Nothing make/MakeFile specific, the variable/command that uses it somehow. You should ask the kernel developers or checkout where it is used

Answer (score 0):

[First hit on Google](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/Misc/Unix-info/make/make_7.html)

It is possible and there is an endif (in the end you need something to close the conditional block after all; if there's none the rest of the file is part of the conditional I guess). The only real big difference to regular conditionals seen in other languages is, that these conditionals are evaluated only once - before the makefile is actually executed. So they're like preprocessor defines and less like a real scripting language. I'm not sure on how widely this is supported (i.e. in non-GNU make alternatives). But this looks like an interesting alternative to using shell scripts/configure/cmake/etc. for simple conditionals and decisions.